# Reprojecting a pointcloud into a local coordinate system with PDAL?

Tags: pdal

I am currently facing the challenge of bringing a point cloud (las) from the coordinate system NAD83(2011) / South Carolina https://epsg.io/6569 into a local coordinate system.
I have been given the following parameters:

- Delta X: 497104
- Delta Y: 338987
- Rotation: 32.68° clockwise

Now I would like to use PDAL - filters.reprojection
( https://pdal.io/stages/filters.reprojection.html ) to do this. But the two examples do not help me.

Is there a way to project this, because unfortunately I have found so far no solutions -.-